# How do I draw a smooth line chart with ios-charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I'm using ios-charts `Charts` to draw a line chart. I'd like to draw a point every 10 min for a 24h period but my x-axis labels needs to show labels every 4 hours like: 12AM 4 8 12PM 4 8. The problem I run into is Charts complaining that the number of data points does not match the number of x-axes values.

What's the best way do do this type of chart? It can't be that hard. Maybe I just learn to love the warning?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you add enough X values to conform the amount of Y values
2. use [xAxis setLabelsToSkip:23] (24 xAxis values for 10 min delta in 4 hours)

swift definition: public func setLabelsToSkip(count: Int)

Objective-C: - (void)setLabelsToSkip:(NSInteger)count